# MongoDB, Mongoose, and composite _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

New to Mongodb & Mongoose.js.

I have created the following schema & model:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    _id: {part1: String, part2: Number},
    name: String
    });
 mongoose.model('myDoc', schema);
```

I can save this, and when I view it on the mongo command line, it looks fine.

However in mongoose when I do:

```
myDoc.find({}, function(err, recs) {
var rec = recs[0];
console.log('----' + JSON.stringify(rec));
});
```

I get my object printed out, but with the following exception: `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"`

I've seen a few explanations, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, and how I need to fix it.

According to mongodb documentation the _id can be bson-type.  What am I doing wrong?  Isn't {part1: String, part2: Number} a bson?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, ok thanks pls add it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoose-orm/yp_hHanUruo/ffM3WQPD-i8J) from the Mongoose author, compound `_id` fields aren't yet supported by Mongoose.

Comment: Thanks, I just use the default mongo _id.  Instead created a unique complex index.